# How the data management is done in Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: storage

Anyone who have a good idea about ethereum blockchain storage can send me some docs to get a good idea for myself?

i am in a full confused state.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum uses a key-value database library, LevelDB

the account(private key or contract) is a basic unit of storage

key(address value)
(account object - nonce, balance, codeHash, stroageRoot)

and all data is stored encrypted

[Patricia Tree document](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Patricia-Tree)

your question is general, so if you point specific topic, I will try to find related document

Comment: Thanks @TLHBM ,What i am confused is how to get and do search functionality on my data.

Comment: LevelDB does not support search functionality. users must access data by key